# TypeScript - ensure array has all values that are in string literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to type an array to ensure it has at the exact values that exist in a string literal? (not necessarily in the same order)

My attempt below warns if an incorrect value is passed, but not if one is missing.

Is this possible?

```
export type IconProps = {
  name: 'arrow-up' | 'arrow-down' | 'chevron-up' | 'chevron-down'
} & React.SVGAttributes<SVGElement>


type IconArr = IconProps['name'][]
const arr: IconArr = ['arrow-up', 'arrow-down', 'chevron-up'] // <-  should complain that 'chevron-down' missing.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just reverse the types:

```
 const arr = <const> ['arrow-up', 'arrow-down', 'chevron-up'];

 export type IconProps = {
   name: (typeof arr)[number]
 } & React.SVGAttributes<SVGElement>
```

[`<const>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510) ensures that the `tyepof arr` is a tuple type, and not a `string[]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, what is the [number] syntax doing in this example?

Comment: @samuel `typeof arr` is a tuple type, but name shouldnt be a tuple, but it should rather be an element of the tuple. By using the *lookup type* `number` you can get that type

Answer (score -3):

you can just try this:-

const arr =  ['arrow-up', 'arrow-down', 'chevron-up']

console.log(typeof arr);